# angular2 rc1 default route issue when refresh page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In RC1's new router the **useAsDefault** can no longer be used. Instead the default route now is implemented in app.component.ts via

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
```

If I refresh my page by pressing the **Reload** button on the browser, then my current page url, for example, `http://localhost:3000/heroshell/heroes` will be changed to `http://localhost:3000/login` because each time I hit Reload button it will go through app.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
```

My current page will still be displayed, but with a error.

```
browser_adapter.ts:78 EXCEPTION: Error in app/apps/hero/hero-shell.component.html:3:7
browser_adapter.ts:78 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
```

Here is app/apps/hero/hero-shell.component.html

```
<my-app1>
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<nav>
    <a [routerLink]="['dashboard']">Dashboard</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['heroes']">Heroes</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</my-app1>
```

So my questions are

1. What is "property 'map' of null" is referred to?
2. Is there any way to make a default route without going through ngOnInit()?
3. Or how to resolve this URL and page content inconsistency during page reload?

Beta routing does not have such behavior because there is no need to go through ngOnInit() to define a default route.

For further info on my folder structure and route setup, see [Angular2 RC1 child routes defined but not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37126836/angular2-rc1-child-routes-defined-but-not-recognized/37129584#37129584)

Update:
If I use

```
  { path: '/', component: Login },
```

paired with

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
```

Then the URL will be changed to `http://localhost:3000/` when the reload button is hit and the error remains the same.

Same way, if I change the path to '*' with the above update then when reload button is hit the URL will be changed to 'http://localhost:3000/*' and the error remains the same.

The key to resolve the problem is the use of a combination of 2 things:

1. Define the root path using either '/' or '*' in @Routes in app.component.ts

   { path: '*', component: Login },
2. Get rid of `ngOnInit()` in app.component.ts so that it won't change the URL.

Again, thanks for the input from you all. cheers:)

Comment: I saw the error message in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8567

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, didn't understand 1st and 3rd questions,  but for this:

> 2. Is there any way to make a default route without going through ngOnInit()?

have you tried '*' as a default route?

```html
{ path: '/heroshell', component: HeroShellComponent },
{ path: '/home',  component: HomeComponent },
{ path: '/login', component: Login }, 
{ path: '*', component: Login },
```

default route will be 'Login' and '/login' path will also work.

Comment: Splaktar, Which router are you using @angular/router or @angular/router-depreciated?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either with @angular/router. The whole idea of upgrading to rc1 is not use deprecated stuff anymore :)

Comment: New Router. Tried '/', and '*'. Not sure that I tried ''.

Answer (score 6):

in RC1 what works for me is

`{ path: '', component: FooComponent, index: true }
{ path: 'foo', component: FooComponent }`

Comment: @Shawn to be precise, it worked for me with the `@angular/router` `3.0.0-alpha.3` in combination with `@angular` in version `2.0.0-rc.1` and in version `2.0.0-rc.2`

Answer (score 3):

```
@Routes([

   { path: '/', component: HomeComponent },

   { path: '/about', component: AboutComponent }
])
```

Out of these two component, the Homecomponent will be the default one.

## UPDATE TO RC5

> With RC5 you cannot have '/' in your path. Instead use ' ' or use '*'

Comment: With RC5 you cannot have '/' in you're path. Instead use ' ' or use '*'

Answer (score 0):

One way to define a default routes with the new RC router is

```
@Routes([
    { path: '/',  component: Login }
])
```

Comment: Is it the *first* route you are defining in your @Routes collection?

Answer (score 0):

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
            { path: '', component: LoginComponent },/*default*/
            { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }/*matches all*/
        ])
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
```

The empty path in the 2nd route matches as the default path for each level of routing. It also allows for adding routes without extending the URL path.

The ** in the last route denotes a wildcard path for our route. The router will match this route if the URL requested doesn't match any paths for routes defined in our configuration. This is useful for displaying a 404 page or redirecting to another route.

The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html